# When does it make sense to buy normal crates?

Tags: pocket-trains

[According to the wiki](http://www.pockettrainswiki.com/wiki/Crates), normal crates cost level x 400 coins. Depending on your level this could easily be in the thousands to ten thousands range.

On the other hand, you can get crates as cargo, occupying a space of 1. Compared to an equivalent piece of cargo, the opportunity cost is in the 10-100 coin range. That's a bargain compared to buying crates.

So perhaps when you have a glut of coins it makes sense, but in my experience I've always found ways to spend coins - new railroads, tracks, or special crates - so when does it ever make sense to purchase regular crates?

Comment: I think that the only time that buying a regular crate makes sense is when you are very early in the game and in desperate need of parts. As you increase in level, the price of the crates go up. Also the number of trains that the part could be used for goes up, making it more and more unlikely that the part you receive will be for something that you immediately need.